# python recursive function and global variable error

Tags: python

I am simulating code to erase all zero at the beginning of a string.

```
def fact(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)
```

my code:

```
class Solution:
    def eraseZero(self,x):
        if str(x)[0]!='0':
            x = str(x)[0:]
            return x
        else:
            x = str(x)[1:]
        return eraseZero(x)



s1 = Solution()
s1.eraseZero('000789')
print(s1.eraseZero('000789'))
```

however I got an error:

> D:\Python27\python.exe D:/pyProject/LintCode&LeetCode/medium.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/pyProject/LintCode&LeetCode/medium.py", line 13, in 
>       s1.eraseZero('000789')   File "D:/pyProject/LintCode&LeetCode/medium.py", line 8, in eraseZero
>       return eraseZero(x) NameError: global name 'eraseZero' is not defined

why? and how to fix.thanks in advance!

Comment: `eraseZero`is not global. It is a method of `Solution`, so you should call it on an instance of `Solution`, i.e. `return self.eraseZero(x)`

Comment: Your `eraseZero` function never uses `self`, so it really shouldn't be a method. And then `Solution` wouldn't have any methods, so it shouldn't exist. All you need is a global `eraseZero` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `eraseZero` is a part of class `Solution` and not globally defined, you should use the instance, `self` in this case, of that class to call it, whether you call it inside or outside the class.

```
class Solution:
    def eraseZero(self,x):
        if str(x)[0]!='0':
            x = str(x)[0:]
            return x
        else:
            x = str(x)[1:]
        return self.eraseZero(x) # <-----------



s1 = Solution()
s1.eraseZero('000789')
print(s1.eraseZero('000789'))
```